# React: Slate state value in a custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, closures

I have a custom react hook `useSearchAllLocations()` like below returning a method `fetchLocations()`

```
export const useSearchAllLocations = (isFilterSelected = false) => {
  console.log('Outer isFilterSelected ', isFilterSelected);
  const fetchLocations = useCallback(
    async () => {
      console.log('Inner isFilterSelected ', isFilterSelected);
      // Some async functionality...
    },
    [isFilterSelected],
  );
  return { fetchLocations };
};
```

I am consuming this hook in a component like this

```
const isFilterSelected = useSelector(isFilterSelectedSelector);
const { fetchLocations } = useSearchAllLocations(isFilterSelected);
```

In the component, there is a onSearch function which has the `fetchLocations()` call.

```
  const onSearch = () => {
    // Some code...
    fetchLocations();
  };
```

The `onSearch` function is called on a button click event and also it is passed as `prop` to a child component. The child component then calls the `onSearch` function on some user events leading to invoking `fetchLocations()`.

When isFilterSelected is changed in the component, the hook re-triggered as expected and displaying the correct value of the isFilterSelected param in the hook from the log - `console.log('Outer isFilterSelected ', isFilterSelected);`

But the value of the variable seems stale for the `fetchLocations()` call from the component from the log - `console.log('Inner isFilterSelected ', isFilterSelected);` and does not match the outer log. Why is the isFilterSelected value stale from the log - `console.log('Inner isFilterSelected ', isFilterSelected);`

I have well provided `isFilterSelected` as a dependency to the `useCallback` and even tried removing the `useCallback` wrapper, still the issue persists.

I understand that a closure is created when the `useSearchAllLocations` hook is called initially, so the value of `isFilterSelected` at that time in the `fetchLocations` method in it is the initial value, which is `false`. But when the value of `isFilterSelected` is changed in the component, shouldn't the re-invocation of `useSearchAllLocations` hook update the previous closure with a new one for the `fetchLocations` method as per the lexical scope?

Comment: Can you share how/where `fetchLocations` is being called?

Comment: @NickParsons, added details in the question now

Comment: Thanks, and to make sure, is `onSearch` memoized, or passed to its own `useCallback()` call in anyway? Also, is the child component memoized (ie: is it wrapped in `React.memo()` by chance). I guess I'm trying to see if `onSearch` is calling the correct "version" of `fetchLocations`, which I guess you can check by logging `isFilterSelected` inside of  `onSearch` and seeing if it logs the new value or the old one.